# Postgresql : Repeat operations on 50 tables of the same schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am new to Postgresql (v.13). I have 50 tables into a "ign" schema (schema other than public). I would like for each of these 50 tables:

- Add a prefix to the name of the table: "IGN_bdTopo_"
- Add a suffix to the table name: "_V1"
- Create a new "date" column of date type. And populate this field with the value: 06/15/2021
- Create a new "source" column of type varchar (length 50). And populate this field with the value: 'ign'.
- Move all the elements of these 50 tables (including all). from the "ign" schema to the "ign_v2" schema. Whether data, constraints, indexes.

Can someone could help me?

Comment: Check the different options for ALTER TABLE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Unrelated, but: [Don't use upper case table or column names](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)

Comment: Do you want the table changes in both schema or just the new schema?

Comment: Just in the new schema

Answer (score 2):

For bulk operations like that, `psql`'s `\gexec` is invaluable. It allows you to write an SQL statement that generates SQL statements and then execute each result row as a statement.  For the rename, that could look like this:

```
SELECT format(
          'ALTER TABLE ign.%I RENAME TO %i',
          table_name,
          'IGN_bdTopo_' || table_name || 'V1'
       )
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'ign'
  AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' \gexec
```

The metadata views in `information_schema` are very useful for this, and the `format()` function makes it easy to avoid SQL injection problems.

I recommend **not** to use upper case characters in object names.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me via which interface do you execute this code please? Via the  pg admin 's query tool, the \gexec seems to be not recognized.

Comment: I said `psql`, which is the PostgreSQL command line client. pgAdmin can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code structure will be as below. You can add other operations which you need.

```
DO $$

DECLARE
table_names text;
schema_names text='public';


BEGIN

FOR table_names IN 
select table_name  FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = schema_names
LOOP
RAISE NOTICE 'added columns to %', table_names;

EXECUTE 'alter table "'||schema_names||'"."' || table_names || '" add  column if not exists  date date ';
EXECUTE 'alter table "'||schema_names||'"."' || table_names || '" add column if not exists source character varying(50)';


END LOOP;

END;

$$;
```

Comment: change schema_names parameter from public to ign